# Parse DateTime from MySQL database

Tags: mysql, perl, datetime

I'm having issues parsing dates from a MySQL result. I'm certain that it has to do with the value being inside a multi-level hash, but I am not sure where I need to mutate the element to get the desired effect

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

use Data::Dumper;
use DBI;
use DateTime::Format::MySQL;

use DateTime::Format::DateParse;
our $now  = DateTime->now(time_zone=>'America/New_York');

my $dbh = DBI->connect('DBI:mysql:database=cacti;host=localhost;port=3306', 'user', 'password');
my $sth = $dbh->prepare('
    SELECT hostname, description, notes, status, disabled, status_rec_date
    FROM host; 
');
$sth->execute();
my $ref = $sth->fetchall_hashref('hostname');
$sth->finish;
$dbh->disconnect();

print Dumper verify($ref->{$_}) for (keys %{$ref});

sub verify {
    my $node = shift;

    my $date = $node->{'status_rec_date'};
    #my $date = '2017-06-25 00:55:00';

    $node->{elapsed} = DateTime::Format::DateParse->parse_datetime($date);

    return $node->{elapsed};
}
```

Dates are stored in the database in the format `2017-06-25 00:55:00`, which is consistent with the input example in `DateTime::Format::MySQL` (which I have also tried in addition to `DateTime::Format::DateParse`).

If I manually set `$date` to `2017-06-25 00:55:00` then all works as expected, however when I pass that string in the form of a hash element, or assign that hash element to a variable, the script fails.

#### Error when using hashref:

```
$ ./hosts.pl 
Validation failed for type named DayOfMonth declared in package DateTime::Types (/usr/local/lib64/perl5/DateTime/Types.pm) at line 29 in sub named (eval) with value 00

Trace begun at Specio::Exception->new line 57
Specio::Exception::throw('Specio::Exception', 'message', 'Validation failed for type named DayOfMonth declared in package DateTime::Types (/usr/local/lib64/perl5/DateTime/Types.pm) at line 29 in sub named (eval) with value 00', 'type', 'Specio::Constraint::Simple=HASH(0x3925e08)', 'value', 00) called at (eval 256) line 85
DateTime::_check_new_params('hour', 00, 'minute', 00, 'month', 0, 'second', 0, 'day', 00, 'year', 1900, 'time_zone', -0400) called at /usr/local/lib64/perl5/DateTime.pm line 165
DateTime::new('DateTime', 'hour', 00, 'minute', 00, 'month', 0, 'second', 0, 'day', 00, 'year', 1900, 'time_zone', -0400) called at /usr/local/share/perl5/DateTime/Format/DateParse.pm line 75
DateTime::Format::DateParse::parse_datetime('DateTime::Format::DateParse', '0000-00-00 00:00:00') called at hosts.pl line 43
```

Comment: Your error suggests you are not getting a valid date out of your database, i.e. the field is null and got turned into `0000-00-00 00:00:00`.  Check your database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious debugging step would be to print the value of `$node->{'status_rec_date'}` inside your `verify()` subroutine. I suspect you'll find that the data isn't what you think it is.

Looking at the stacktrace in your error message, the outer call is:

> DateTime::Format::DateParse::parse_datetime('DateTime::Format::DateParse', '0000-00-00 00:00:00') called at hosts.pl line 43

You're passing in "0000-00-00 00:00:00". And that's not a valid date string.

So it seems the problem is in your database. I'll note that the string you're getting is an invalid date that MySQL seems to like to insert into datetime fields when it doesn't have a valid value - so you might want to look at how that field is populated.

Comment: MySQL is storing null dates as all zeros, I'm tentatively restting those to epoch start:

    $date = '1970-01-01 00:00:00' if $node->{status_rec_date} eq '0000-00-00 00:00:00';

Comment: Is it a nullable column? Surely a null is better than an invalid date? I think that you can put MySQL into a "strict" mode where it won't allow invalid data like this.

Comment: The database is the backend for Cacti, I don't want to change anything schemawise in fear that it will break the designed usage for that application. If 0's are not a valid date in Perl modules, then I am setting the date manually to start of epoch which I've seen consistently used  elsewhere as Null for dates.

Comment: And here we see why people should be licensed before being allowed to design databases :-)